# Consistency techniques for federated distributed systems (DB CAP, Simulations, etc.)

Tags: nosql, couchdb, azure-cosmosdb, distributed-computing

I am looking for an authoritative source of techniques used for consistency management (something better than best effort). A guideline, book, or other resource would be great.

For example, in distributed cloud dbs, I am familiar with the five techniques offered by Azure CosmosDB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels (and of course, Dynamo, CouchDB, etc. similar approaches)

In simulation. HLA (High Level Architecture) has a "ACID" level of distributed update with a peer-peer system. See: https://www.acm-sigsim-mskr.org/Courseware/Fujimoto/Slides/FujimotoSlides-21-HLATimeManagement.pdf

The best survey I found was https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACELC_theorem , but It is pretty thin.

If there is not a survey, is there some faculty at some university who has made this his/her career that we could consult with?

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative source on this (in my humble opinion) is Martin Kleppmann and his book [Designing Data-Intensive Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321). In particular, chapter 9 deals with consistency models, although there are other chapters that talk about replication and other issues related to building distributed databases so Chapter 9 itself should be read with the others.